# How to display a connected component image with threshold of some specific property say 'Area'

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, connected-components

I found an image's connected components using

```
La=bwlabel(labeledImage,8); %%% labeledImage is a binary image
figure,imshow(La,[]);
coloredLabel = label2rgb (La, 'hsv', 'k', 'shuffle');
imshow(coloredLabel);
```

now I want to show (display), in Matlab,  connected components (in color) which have area less than that of '7' pixels and more than '7' separately, as two different images. Can someone Help me please.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The above implementation is being done in Matlab....Sorry forgot to mention earlier......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit tricky, but here's one way of doing this using [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html):

```
pr = regionprops( La, 'Area', 'PixelIdxList' );

smallArea = La;
small_select = [pr.Area] <= 7; %// select regions smaller than 7 pixels
smallArea( vertcat( pr(~small_select).PixelIdxList ) ) = 0; %// set all other regions to zero
imshow( smallArea ); colormap( rand(max(smallArea(:)), 3) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. But it gives the following error of dimension mismatch Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in Piyu_HNV_Sir_Manifestated (line 121)
smallArea([pr(~small_select).PixelIdxList]) = 0; %// set all other regions to zero

Comment: @DrEma please see my edit (adding `vertcat`): `smallArea( vertcat( pr(~small_select).PixelIdxList ) ) = 0;`

Comment: Sorry. I am new to stackoverflow, didn't got how to vote ('V'). Can you please describe it a bit. Thank You.

Comment: I have a gray scale image add1,however there are only two pixel intensities in it (0 for Black and 255 for White).I am able to track the coordinate of my pixel of consideration i.e. add1[i,j]. now I want to display the connected component of which this pixel is part. I have tried it with the regionprop using PixelIdxList and PixelList unsuccesfully.Can you help please.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DrEma your comment is unclear. why don't you [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a new question?